# Contact us form emails stuck in email Queue in kentico cms

Tags: email, content-management-system, kentico, contact-form

I am developing a website using Kentico 9 CMS. I have two websites running on a same web server first one is Dev and second one is the Production(LIVE). I am facing a strange issue with the Contact us form. When someone visit my website and fills the contact us form, it sends the enquiry to the admin via email. This functionality is working fine in Dev version but not working in Production (LIVE) version. In the Production version, those contact us form emails are getting stuck in the email queue tab in the Admin. And I forced to push/send the email manually from the Admin, which works.

I checked both website setting and found that is there is no difference is the email settings. I also checked the error logs also but found nothing in the logs about emails.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is scheduled tasks that triggers sending emails out - is it enabled for production site?